# Populating NSPopupButton with Core Data Entity plus a menu Item

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsmenuitem, nspopupbutton

Is there a way to put the list of a core data entity into a NSPopupButton and additionally put a menu item there?

I have two core data entities, say Person and Car.
A Person has many Cars (relationship).
On a sheet the user should be able to pick a car from a popup button for the person.
This popup button should also offer an option to create a new car, that would then be selected for that person.

My attempts so far:

The items I put into the NSPopupButton in IB do not appear at runtime when the popup is populated from core data.

I can specify an action that gets called when the user selects an item from the popup, but that gets triggered for every item. (I needed to have a dummy entry in the core data entity only to trigger the desired sheet, also I cannot control the position of that dummy item in the popup)

Comment: Did you check out some CoreData tutorials at all?

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for responding,
Yes, I did check a lot of tutorials and sites...

Just to be clear, populating with core data is no problem.
The mix of core data and NSMenuItem is, though.

Comment: Hi Jay, if you think I missed information in the tutorials, could you point me in the right direction please? Thank you.